# Differences between hflush & hsync api's in HDFS

Tags: api, filesystems, hadoop, hdfs

Can someone highlight the technical details and when to use which.

Answer (score 9):

In the current HDFS(0.23.3) implementation, `hflush` and `hsync` is the same. [hsync](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/0.23.3/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Syncable.java#Syncable.hsync%28%29) invokes `hflush`. `hflush` guarantees that flushed data become visible to new readers. It is not guaranteed that data has been flushed to persistent store on the datanode. So using `hflush` may lost some data if the datanode failures happen. `hsync` is designed to guarantee that all data write to the disk device but **is not implemented** now.

In the alpha HDFS 2.0.*, [hsync](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.0.2-alpha/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Syncable.java#Syncable.hsync%28%29) is implemented correctly.

You can get more details in [HBase, HDFS and durable sync](http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com/2012/05/hbase-hdfs-and-durable-sync.html).